# $project field in MongoDB with dates conditional return empty

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongoose, database

I need to return data with standard plains and plains with promotion if today's date is still within the period.

I have already managed to do almost everything, the only problem is that in $project, my condition is correct but returns empty.

Collection of course:

```
{
"_id": "58a4fcc8dddbeb0ba0a84ac8",
"updatedAt": "2017-02-16T10:26:37.841Z",
"createdAt": "2017-02-16T01:13:44.936Z",
"name": "Engenharia da computação",
"hours": 5000,
"AreaId": "58a4eec3aa912c63b241698d",
"PriceId": "58a4fbd3dddbeb0ba0a84ac0",
"ModalityId": "584e073edde7042be39b31a2",
"__v": 0,
"isActive": true
```

}

Collection of Price:

```
{
"_id": "58a4fbd3dddbeb0ba0a84ac0",
"description": "Preço de banana",
"__v": 0,
"promotions": [
  {
    "name": "Promoção de natal",
    "rules": "Somente valido no notal",
    "startsAt": "2017-01-16T17:12:26.289Z",
    "expiresAt": "2017-07-16T17:12:26.289Z",
    "_id": "58a4fbd3dddbeb0ba0a84ac1",
    "isActive": false,
    "plains": [
      {
        "parcels": 1,
        "from": 1800,
        "to": 1500,
        "_id": "58a4fbd3dddbeb0ba0a84ac4"
      },
      {
        "parcels": 2,
        "from": 900,
        "to": 800,
        "_id": "58a4fbd3dddbeb0ba0a84ac3"
      },
      {
        "parcels": 3,
        "from": 400,
        "to": 300,
        "_id": "58a4fbd3dddbeb0ba0a84ac2"
      }
    ]
  }
],
"plains": [
  {
    "parcels": 1,
    "from": 2000,
    "to": 1600,
    "_id": "58a4fbd3dddbeb0ba0a84ac7"
  },
  {
    "parcels": 2,
    "from": 1000,
    "to": 999,
    "_id": "58a4fbd3dddbeb0ba0a84ac6"
  },
  {
    "parcels": 3,
    "from": 500,
    "to": 400,
    "_id": "58a4fbd3dddbeb0ba0a84ac5"
  }
]
```

}

I will receive from a form the parcels in number, example: '1 or 2 parcels'.
If this exists in the 'plains' documents in promotions, you should search, but you should check the dates if the promotion has not expired, otherwise you should look for default plains value.

This is my query:

```
Course
        .aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    _id: ObjectId(req.body.CourseId)
                }
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    'from'        : 'prices',
                    'localField'  : 'PriceId',
                    'foreignField': '_id',
                    'as'          : 'price'
                }
            },
            {
                $redact: {
                    $cond: {
                        if  : {
                            $or: [
                                {$eq: ['$parcels', 1]},
                                {$or: '$price'},
                                {$or: '$promotions'},
                                {$or: '$plains'},
                            ]
                        },
                        then: "$$DESCEND",
                        else: "$$PRUNE"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    promotions: {
                        $filter: {
                            input: "$price.promotions",
                            as   : "promotion",
                            cond : {$and: [
                                {$lte: ["$$promotion.startsAt", new Date]},
                                {$gte: ["$$promotion.expiresAt", new Date]}
                            ]}
                        }
                    },
                    plains    : "$price.plains"
                }
            }
        ])
```

The return is this:

```
{
  "_id": "58a4fcc8dddbeb0ba0a84ac8",
  "promotions": [],
  "plains": [
    [
      {
        "parcels": 1,
        "from": 2000,
        "to": 1600,
        "_id": "58a4fbd3dddbeb0ba0a84ac7"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Theoretically the array of promotions should not come empty, it's like this:

```
[
    {
      "name": "February Promotion",
      "rules": "Valid only in February",
      "startsAt": "2017-01-16T17:12:26.289Z",
      "expiresAt": "2017-07-16T17:12:26.289Z",
      "_id": "58a4fbd3dddbeb0ba0a84ac1",
      "plains": [
        {
          "parcels": 1,
          "from": 1800,
          "to": 1500,
          "_id": "58a4fbd3dddbeb0ba0a84ac4"
        },
        {
          "parcels": 2,
          "from": 900,
          "to": 800,
          "_id": "58a4fbd3dddbeb0ba0a84ac3"
        },
        {
          "parcels": 3,
          "from": 400,
          "to": 300,
          "_id": "58a4fbd3dddbeb0ba0a84ac2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a sample doc from both the `course` and `prices` collection that you are expecting your query to return ?

Comment: I just edit the post with your request. @Veeram

Comment: Your `expiresAt` is before the current date time.  So `{$gte: ["$$promotion.expiresAt", new Date]}` fails when you compare with current datetime.

Comment: ExpireDate = "2017-07-16T17:12:26.289Z" > (new Date).toISOString()
return true

Comment: That doesn't sound right the currrent UTC time is `2017-02-16T19:35:55.168Z`.I think you are doing string date comparison which is not reliable way of comparing date values. Is your date values store as `string` ?